# Do Chunks of Taelosian Rock still drop?

Tags: everquest

I'm working on finishing [Expert Fletcher Test](http://everquest.allakhazam.com/db/quest.html?quest=3914) that I started years ago. I just need to make [CLASS 5 Bone Serrated Tip Arrow](http://www.eqtraders.com/items/show_item.php?item=10772), but I can't seem to find any [Chunks of Taelosian Rock](http://everquest.allakhazam.com/db/item.html?item=26012#end) to make the [Serrated Arrowheads](http://www.eqtraders.com/items/show_item.php?item=10671) out of. Do the chunks of rock still drop in Natimbi? What kind of drop rate am I looking at?

Comment: I do not have an answer but +1 for eq question :D

Comment: I ended up buying them on the AH.